# Why am I getting SQL State: 28000 FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user error message when running a simple Java program?

Tags: java, postgresql, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org) 11 database installed on a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) virtual machine running [Centos7](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/7/isos/x86_64/) (guest machine), and my host machine is a Mac OS Catalina.  Both the guest (Centos) and host (Catalina) have JDK 8 installed.

I have the following simple Java code that uses a single dependency [postgresql-42.2.5](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar):

```
public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5332/mydb", "mydbuser", "mydbpassword")) {

            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

I compile and run this on my host (Catalina) :

```
java -jar JavaApplication5.jar
```

and the output I get is:

```
Connected to the database!
```

So clearly this means I can connect to the Postgres database from my host to my guest. Next, I test whether I can connect directly from my guest.  So I copy "JavaApplication5.jar" into guest Virtual Machine running Centos 7 and re-run the same command.  However, this time I am getting the following message from the same executable jar file:

```
SQL State: 28000
FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "mydbuser"
```

Does anybody know why I am getting this error on the guest virtual machine but not on the host?

Here is the relevant portion of my my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: It looks like you are coming from localhost, so one of the `ident` lines matches. But either you are a different operating system user, or the ident server thinks that you are some different user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have port forwarding set up in your VirtualBox to capture connection attempts on the host to that port and route them to the VB.  So while you specify 127.0.0.1, they are coming from someplace else as far as PostgreSQL is concerned.  That matches the 'md5' line of your pg_hba.conf.  When done from the guest, the connections really are coming from 127.0.0.1, and so match the earlier 'ident' line.

The 'ident' authentication is failing, for reasons surely mentioned in the log file.  If you don't want to use 'ident', remove those lines.

Comment: You were on point.  I changed the 2nd line above in pg_hba.conf to look like host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're using hardcoded 127.0.0.1 on both machines. 127.0.0.1 should swapped out to be the IP address of the database host or it's FQDN. 5332 instead of 5432 is unusual.

Comment: What is unusual about 5332?